# RecyclerView Adapter getItemCount not called for IceCreamSandwich

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

There is a case where `getItemCount` within the `RecycerView` Adapter is not called for Android 4.0.3 (`IceCreamSandwich`). All other API versions don't have any problems. I create my adapter as follows:

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "array size = " + myArray.size());
adapter = new MyListAdapter(context, myArray, this);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I inserted the `Log.i` to confirm there is an element in the array, which there is. Within the `RecyclerView` Adapter's constructor, I have:

```
public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<dataModel> data, MyListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mData = data;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mListener = listener;

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "data size = " + this.mData.size());
}
```

And the data size is not empty within the constructor. What could be causing the `getItemCount` to not be called when the adapter is created and set to a `RecyclerView`? Again this only is happening with the `IceCreamSandwich` API, all others work perfectly.

Comment: How do you know that `getItemCount` is not being called and why do you require it?

Comment: I put logging within `getItemCount` and even `onCreateViewHolder` and neither get called. `getItemCount` tells the adapter how many data items there are, and of course `onCreateViewHolder` creates the views for the adapter.

Comment: Beats me... Can you try with a couple other ICS devices and see if this behavior is reproduced?

Comment: It was reported by a user of the app running `IceCreamSandwich`, and I had to use emulators for that version of Android. That's the only version which has this behavior.